# Painting a QVideoFrame on a QVideoWidget with QT6

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to process the stream of my webcam frame by frame with QT6. I've checked the internet but since QTMultimedia was heavily reworked with QT6, and since QT6 is pretty new, all the documentation/questions available are outdated.

So, In order to achieve my goal, I'm using a `QMediaCaptureSession` with a camera set on `QMediaDevices::defaultVideoInput()`. I checked that this was working by setting the video output of the `QMediaCaptureSession` to a `QVideoWidget` with `m_session.setVideoOutput(ui->videowidget);`, and it's working fine, except that I can't process the frames (basically, it's rendering my webcam on the `QVideoWidget`).

Now, to process the frames, I have to use a `QVideoSink` as far as I understand the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvideosink.html) and [there](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediacapturesession.html#setVideoSink). So I replaced `m_session.setVideoOutput(ui->videowidget);` with `m_session.setVideoSink(&mysink);`, where `mysink` is a `QVideoSink`.

Then, since I want to process the frames, I'm connecting the `videoFrameChanged` signal of `mysink` to a function `processVideoFrame` where I want to do 2 things :

1. process the current frame
2. render the result on the UI, ideally on `ui->videowidget`

This is the point where I'm struggling. **I do not understand how to use the `paint` [function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvideoframe.html#paint) of the class `QVideoFrame` to render the processed frame on the `QVideoWidget`**. More precisely :

- I do not understand how I'm supposed to instantiate the `QPainter`. I tried a straightforward `new QPainter(ui->videowidget)` but it ends up in a `QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called` exception and nothing is rendered
- I do not understand what is actually representing the second parameter `rect` of `QVideoFrame::paint`?

I made a MWE, code is below.

*mwe_videosinkpainting.h*

```
#ifndef MWE_VIDEOSINKPAINTING_H
#define MWE_VIDEOSINKPAINTING_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMediaCaptureSession>
#include <QMediaDevices>
#include <QCamera>
#include <QVideoSink>
#include <QPainter>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MWE_VideoSinkPainting; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MWE_VideoSinkPainting : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MWE_VideoSinkPainting(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MWE_VideoSinkPainting();

private slots:
    void processVideoFrame();


private:
    Ui::MWE_VideoSinkPainting *ui;

    QVideoSink mysink;
    QMediaCaptureSession m_session;
    QScopedPointer<QCamera> m_camera;
};
#endif // MWE_VIDEOSINKPAINTING_H
```

*mwe_videosinking.cpp*

```
#include "mwe_videosinkpainting.h"
#include "ui_mwe_videosinkpainting.h"

MWE_VideoSinkPainting::MWE_VideoSinkPainting(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MWE_VideoSinkPainting)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_camera.reset(new QCamera(QMediaDevices::defaultVideoInput()));
    m_session.setCamera(m_camera.data());
    //m_session.setVideoOutput(ui->videowidget);

    connect(&mysink, &QVideoSink::videoFrameChanged, this, &MWE_VideoSinkPainting::processVideoFrame);

    m_session.setVideoSink(&mysink);
    m_camera->start();
}

MWE_VideoSinkPainting::~MWE_VideoSinkPainting()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MWE_VideoSinkPainting::processVideoFrame()
{
    QVideoFrame videoframe = mysink.videoFrame();
    if(videoframe.map(QVideoFrame::ReadOnly))
    {
        //This is the part I'm struggling to understand and achieve
        videoframe.paint(new QPainter(ui->videowidget), QRectF(0.0f,0.0f,100.0f,100.0f), QVideoFrame::PaintOptions());
        videoframe.unmap();
    }
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "mwe_videosinkpainting.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MWE_VideoSinkPainting w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

*ui_mwe_videosinkpainting.h (just so that you have the whole code, it has no value for the question)*

```
#ifndef UI_MWE_VIDEOSINKPAINTING_H
#define UI_MWE_VIDEOSINKPAINTING_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtMultimediaWidgets/QVideoWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MWE_VideoSinkPainting
{
public:
    QWidget *centralwidget;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QVideoWidget *videowidget;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QMenuBar *menubar;
    QStatusBar *statusbar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MWE_VideoSinkPainting)
    {
        if (MWE_VideoSinkPainting->objectName().isEmpty())
            MWE_VideoSinkPainting->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MWE_VideoSinkPainting"));
        MWE_VideoSinkPainting->resize(800, 600);
        centralwidget = new QWidget(MWE_VideoSinkPainting);
        centralwidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralwidget"));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(centralwidget);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
        videowidget = new QVideoWidget(centralwidget);
        videowidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("videowidget"));
        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(videowidget);
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(videowidget, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        MWE_VideoSinkPainting->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);
        menubar = new QMenuBar(MWE_VideoSinkPainting);
        menubar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menubar"));
        menubar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 21));
        MWE_VideoSinkPainting->setMenuBar(menubar);
        statusbar = new QStatusBar(MWE_VideoSinkPainting);
        statusbar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusbar"));
        MWE_VideoSinkPainting->setStatusBar(statusbar);

        retranslateUi(MWE_VideoSinkPainting);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MWE_VideoSinkPainting);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MWE_VideoSinkPainting)
    {
        MWE_VideoSinkPainting->setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication::translate("MWE_VideoSinkPainting", "MWE_VideoSinkPainting", nullptr));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MWE_VideoSinkPainting: public Ui_MWE_VideoSinkPainting {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MWE_VIDEOSINKPAINTING_H
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot format code in a comment...

So, you mean change this...

```cpp
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_camera.reset(new QCamera(QMediaDevices::defaultVideoInput()));
    m_session.setCamera(m_camera.data());
    //m_session.setVideoOutput(ui->videowidget);
    connect(&mysink, &QVideoSink::videoFrameChanged, this, &MWE_VideoSinkPainting::processVideoFrame);
    m_session.setVideoSink(&mysink);
    m_camera->start();
```

...to this?

```cpp
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_camera.reset(new QCamera(QMediaDevices::defaultVideoInput()));
    m_session.setCamera(m_camera.data());
    m_session.setVideoSink(&mysink);
    m_session.setVideoOutput(ui->videowidget);
    connect(&mysink, &QVideoSink::videoFrameChanged, this, &MWE_VideoSinkPainting::processVideoFrame);
    m_camera->start();
```

I did this and I am still only getting black in my videoWidget.

Comment: exactly I guess sadly the only way is to use the sink, then paint the frames manually to some custom widget

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite straightforward : you can use `setVideoSink` AND `setVideoOutput`.

The code I gave in OP is good, you just have to uncomment `setVideoOutput(ui->videowidget);` of *mwe_videosinking.cpp* and to call `setVideoSink` BEFORE calling `setVideoOutput`

Comment: sadly this doesn't work, setVideoSink and setVideoOutput are mutually exclusive according to docs calling either of them unsets the previously set sink or output
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediacapturesession.html#setVideoSink:~:text=a%20QVideoSink.-,The%20previously%20set%20preview%20is%20detached.,-See%20also%20videoSink